# Generating function of a modified multinomial distribution

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

Let

$$\mathcal{M}(\mathbf{x},N,\mathbf{p})=\begin{cases} N! \frac{(1-\sum_{i=1}^n p_i)^{N-\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}}{(N-\sum_{i=1}^n x_i)!} \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{p_k^{x_k}}{x_k!}& \qquad \text{if} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \leq N, \sum_{i=1}^n p_i \leq 1 ~\text{and} ~ \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{N}_0^n \\ 0 &\qquad \text{otherwise}\end{cases}.$$ All $p_i$ are real and positive and $N \in \mathbb{N}$.

I am looking for the generating function of $\mathcal{M}$. Is the following equation correct?
$$\sum_{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \leq N} \mathcal{M}(\mathbf{x},N,\mathbf{p})\prod_{k=1}^n s_k^{x_k} \overset{?}{=} (1-\sum_{i=1}^n p_i + \sum_{i=1}^n p_i s_i)^N $$

I'm having trouble applying the multinomial theorem because of the condition $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \leq N$ for the indices of the summands. Is it possible to apply the mentioned theorem by defining $x_0 = N-\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ and $p_0 = 1-\sum_{i=1}^n p_i$? It seems strange to me having one index $x_0$ that depends on all other indices.